# How do I count the pairs next to one another while using the last and next letter as a possible pair

Tags: python, string, counter

This is the code I have.

```
def count_pairs( s ):
  paired = 0
  unpaired = set(s)
  print unpaired
  for x in unpaired:
    paired = paired + s.count (x + x)
  return paired


print ( count_pairs("ddogccatppig") )
print ( count_pairs("dogcatpig") )
print ( count_pairs("xxyyzz") )
print ( count_pairs("a") )
print ( count_pairs("abc") )
print ( count_pairs("aabb") )
print ( count_pairs("dogcatpigaabbcc") )
print ( count_pairs("aabbccdogcatpig") )
print ( count_pairs("dogabbcccatpig") )
print ( count_pairs("aaaa") )
print ( count_pairs("AAAAAAAAA") )
```

I want to be able to get the pairs without using the set command and while count the last letter in `count_pairs` and the next.

Comment: Do you using the last letter of one string and the first letter of the next one? (so ddogccatppigdogcatpig... etc)

Comment: What is the desired output? Please also clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a count of *non-overlapping* repeated letters, which is what `str.count` returns. You can replicate this via a `while` loop to avoid both `set` and `str.count`:

```
def count_pairs(s):
    c = 0
    i = 0
    while i < len(s)-1:
        if s[i] == s[i+1]:
            c += 1
            i += 2
        else:
            i += 1
    return c
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive solution

```
def count_pairs (s):
  def loop (pairs, x, y = None, *rest):
    if y is None:
      return pairs
    elif x == y:
      return loop (pairs + 1, y, *rest)
    else:
      return loop (pairs, y, *rest)
  return loop (0, *s)

print (count_pairs ("ddogccatppig"))    # 3
print (count_pairs ("dogcatpig"))       # 0
print (count_pairs ("xxyyzz"))          # 3 
print (count_pairs ("a"))               # 0
print (count_pairs ("abc"))             # 0
print (count_pairs ("aabb"))            # 2
print (count_pairs ("dogcatpigaabbcc")) # 3
print (count_pairs ("aabbccdogcatpig")) # 3
print (count_pairs ("dogabbcccatpig"))  # 3
print (count_pairs ("aaaa"))            # 3
print (count_pairs ("AAAAAAAAA"))       # 8
```

Above, the string `aaaa` results in **3** pairs because `[aa]aa`, `a[aa]a`, and `aa[aa]`, where `[..]` denotes a found pair. If you don't want to count overlapping pairs, the `loop` needs to be changed slightly

```
def count_pairs (s):
  def loop (pairs, x = None, y = None, *rest):
    if x is None or y is None:
      return pairs
    elif x == y:
      return loop (pairs + 1, y, *rest)
      return loop (pairs + 1, *rest)
    else:
      return loop (pairs, y, *rest)
  return loop (0, *s)

print (count_pairs ("ddogccatppig"))    # 3
print (count_pairs ("dogcatpig"))       # 0
print (count_pairs ("xxyyzz"))          # 3 
print (count_pairs ("a"))               # 0
print (count_pairs ("abc"))             # 0
print (count_pairs ("aabb"))            # 2
print (count_pairs ("dogcatpigaabbcc")) # 3
print (count_pairs ("aabbccdogcatpig")) # 3
print (count_pairs ("dogabbcccatpig"))  # 2
print (count_pairs ("aaaa"))            # 2
print (count_pairs ("AAAAAAAAA"))       # 4
```